# Cognos - Not same value in Query Studio and Report Studio

Tags: cognos

In Framework Manager I have a query element which calculates the distinct number of a dimension (count distinct for the aggregation in the properties).
In the database, the total of distinct number is 15720813 (so the good number).

Then when I wanna test this object in Query Studio the number displayed is 15723470 which is the total number of records in the table so that's wrong.
But in Report Studio the number displayed is 15720813 which is the good number.

Why Query Studio and Report Studio don't display the same number?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Open the Query Studio report in Report Studio, so you can see what it's actually doing.

Comment: I did this and i saw that the SQL query is a simple count and not a count distinct.

Comment: But when I use Report Studio only, the SQL query is a count distinct...

Comment: Do you happen to have two different framework models?

Comment: I have a deep hatred of Query Studio, for these kinds of reasons.  I would suggest setting the aggregate properties for this column (or create a new one) in Framework Manager to `count distinct`.  Then try using that column in your Query Studio report.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the aggregate property in query studio of the element you are trying to test. It is available below the menu in query studio. 
[image]

It might be you are using different elements. Please check and retry. If not then I would suggest going back and recreating the entire element.